# Force django_compressor to recompile css/less files

Tags: django, apache, apache2, django-compressor

We let users upload their own custom css/less to our django app.

All our css/less files are compressed by [django_compressor](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/) "on-the-fly".

When the app is initially deployed all css files are moved to the `collect-static` directory.

When users upload custom css styles they replace one of the less files in the `collect-static` directory.

The problem with that is that the changes only appear when the apache is being reloaded thus a new css file gets generated by django-compressor.

Is there a way to force django-compressor to regenerate it's compiled and cached files? I would not feel comfortable triggering a `sudo services apache2 reload` at django application level.

Comment: In the mean time, you can use less.js

Comment: Also: http:// code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Comment: We need to compile less server side. Client side is not an option due to possible performance probs.

Comment: The advantage of compiling client side is that the user will be able to see compile errors, ie. due to syntax mistakes. Moving on, if you want to compile user code on the server side, then the django-compressor does not seem to be the right tool for that. What if a user uploads a less file that doesn't compile ? I don't know django-compressor very well, so correct me if I'm wrong, but it *won't* expose less compile errors on the client side. Would that be a problem ? In case, I suggest that you provide a "compile" button to the user and if it fails, display less compiler output. Just my 2c :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a different approach. I am now using offline compression, which is faster and better for multi server deployments anyways.

I give the user an interface to change certain css and less values. I save those css/less values in a database table, so that the user can edit the stuff easily.

To make the new css/less values available to the frontend (compiled css files) I write the values the user entered in a less file to the disk and re-run the `python manage.py compress` command.

This way the compiled compressor files are generated and if the user entered invalid less code, which would lead to compile errors, the compressor stops and keeps the old css files.

Here's my save() method:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        #write the less file to the file system
        #everytime the model is saved
        try:

            file_location = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'styles', 'less', 'custom_styles.less')

            with open(file_location, 'w') as f:
                f.write(render_to_string('custom_styles/custom_stylesheet_tmpl.txt', {'platform_customizations': self}))

        except IOError:
            #TODO show error message to user in admin backend and via messaging system
            raise IOError

        #re-run offline compress command in prod mode
        management.call_command('compress')


        super(PlatformCustomizations, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 5):

I can come up with two possible solutions, I don't like both of them very much.

You can call `compress` ([doc](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/#pre-compression)) from within [incron](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/incron) or cron:

```
python manage.py compress
```

Or you can set a very low `COMPRESS_REBUILD_TIMEOUT`. ([doc](http://django_compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#caching-settings))

BTW you have the user scripts as a seperate bundle, right?